# In a Drupal 8 Bootstrap Subtheme - Bootstrap Views Carousel not working

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, drupal

This is my bootstrap sub theme page--front.html.twig

```
<html>
  <body>   
    <div class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel" id="carousel-1">
      <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
        {{ page.hero }}
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

This is [my live demo](http://minnak.webstudio.web.tr) of my theme. The carousel block works awesome with the original bootstrap theme but with mine it is not working.

Comment: `http://minnak.webstudio.web.tr/themes/minnak/js/scripts.js?of1vjt 404 (Not Found)` you can start there